# Matching and pasting to line

Tags: sed, awk, join

So I have 2 very big text files, consisting of lines like so:

#### First:

```
Robert:Dillain:Other:Other:Other
Julian:Brude:Other:Other:Other
Megan:Flikk:Other:Other:Other
Samantha:Minot:Other:Other:Other
Jesus:Kimmel:Other:Other:Other
```

#### Second:

```
Sb:Minot:amsen
Jbb:Kimmel:verlin
R:Dillain:bodent
Mb:Flikk:kentin
Jb:Brude:kemin
```

I would like to match them both by the **second column** (Dillain, Brude, etc) and paste them to lines like so:

#### OUTPUT:

```
Robert:Dillain:Other:Other:Other:R:Dillain:bodent
Jesus:Kimmel:Other:Other:Other:Jbb:Kimmel:verlin
Samantha:Minot:Other:Other:Other:Sb:Minot:amsen
etc...
etc...
```

I was thinking  of using `sed` for this, but anything Unix based would be great. I have had no luck trying to come up with a way to do this myself.

Comment: Your output record order does not seem to follow that of either input file - is that significant?

Comment: How do you mean? do you mean that it does not seem to be the desired output? Cause it looks like it does but i may have missed something

Comment: will all lines definitely pair?

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a task for `join`:

```
join -t":" -o "1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.1,2.2,2.3" \
   -j 2 <(sort -k2,2 -t: test1) <(sort -k2,2 -t: test2)
```

#### Output:

```
Julian:Brude:Other:Other:Other:Jb:Brude:kemin
Robert:Dillain:Other:Other:Other:R:Dillain:bodent
Megan:Flikk:Other:Other:Other:Mb:Flikk:kentin
Jesus:Kimmel:Other:Other:Other:Jbb:Kimmel:verlin
Samantha:Minot:Other:Other:Other:Sb:Minot:amsen
```

#### Breakdown:

- `-t` set field delimiter to `:`
- `-o` set print format
- `-j` join on column number `2`
- `<(sort -k2,2 -t: file)` pre-sort file by `-k` second column `-t` set field delimiter to `:`

Comment: @mikeserv Good point. I updated it with `-k2,2`. Yeah `join` is a funny useful tool that most tend to forget is on the system -- (I know I do), since not every day I need to join 2 files together. I tend to use `join` as frequently as there are solar eclipses. lol

Answer (score 5):

This is simple task for `awk`:

```
awk -F':' -vOFS=':' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' file2 file1
```

First we set `:` as field separator both for input (with `-F`) and output (with `OFS`) then if first file is processed (`file2`) we assign whole line to table element indexed with second field. When next next file (`file1`) is processed we print its lines adding the line from previous file stored in `a[$2]`).

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` you can probably do:

```
sed 's|[^:]*:\([^:]*\).*|/^[^:]*:\1:/s/$/:&/;t|' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

...which would involve one `sed` process reading the second file and writing a `sed` script for editing the first into a second `sed`'s stdin. As near as I can tell you shouldn't have any problem with directly injecting the contents verbatim into a regexp like that. If there is the possibility of meta-characters in input, there are plenty of answers on this site which discuss means of escaping them. If it might be required, though, the following would be enough:

```
sed 's|[]&\./*[]|\\&|g;s|...' ... | sed -f - file1
```

Still, probably the eponymous `join` is the better solution - this is just to demonstrate how to do it w/ `sed` because you mentioned it.

Anyway, the script that the second `sed` applies to `file1` winds up looking like *(with a line similiar to the below for every line in file2)*:

```
/^[^:]*:Dillain:/s/$/:R:Dillain:bodent/;t
```

...which means that if it encounters a line matching *Dillain* for the second colon-delimited field, then it should append the *:R:Dillain:bodent* string to its tail. Because there's probably no sense in continuing to attempt to match a line in `file1` if a line from `file2` has already been appended, the trailing `t`est command just branches away any successful substitution as soon as it is complete.

Comment: Weird. I was awarded the `awk` tag badge for this: I don't even know how to use `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Through **python3**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
import sys
file1, file2 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
with open(file2) as second, open(file1) as first:
    second_list = second.readlines()
    first_list = first.readlines()
for line1 in first_list:
    for line2 in second_list:
        if line1.split(':')[1] == line2.split(':')[1]:
            print(line1.strip()+line2.strip())
```

Copy and paste the above script in a file called `script.py`. And then run the script by running the below command on the terminal.

```
python3 script.py file1 file2
```